# Why is Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils escapeXML10 not working in groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, apache-commons, stringescapeutils

I have a simple groovy script where I want to escape a String for XML...

```
 @Grapes(@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-lang3',version='3.9'))
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils

 def value = "[Apple MacBook Pro with Touch Bar - 15.4 & Core i7 - 16 GB RAM - 512 GB SSD]"
 StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11​(value.toString())
```

As per the [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml10(java.lang.String)), it looks like this method just needs a String, so why is it giving this exception...

```
 No signature of method: static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11​() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [[Apple MacBook Pro with Touch Bar - 15.4 & Core i7 - 16 GB RAM - 512 GB SSD]]
```

Comment: correction: `escapeXml10​` introduced in version 3.3, so probably you have older version of library. in this case use the deprecated version of method: `escapeXml`

Comment: That's `escapeXml` that's deprecated, not `escapeXml10`. And you're discussing different libraries; commons.lang and commons.text are not the same packages. They may run the same (or similar; text explicitly states it was "adapted" from lang 3.5) code (haven't checked), but they're not the same thing.

Comment: @DaveNewton, and Victor, I updated my code to use commons.lang but I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a non-printable character in your code:

```
  Offset: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F   
00000000: 53 74 72 69 6E 67 45 73 63 61 70 65 55 74 69 6C    StringEscapeUtil
00000010: 73 2E 65 73 63 61 70 65 58 6D 6C 31 31 E2 80 8B    s.escapeXml11b..
00000020: 28 76 61 6C 75 65 2E 74 6F 53 74 72 69 6E 67 28    (value.toString(
00000030: 29 29 0A                                           )).
```

See after the `Xml11`?

It works fine with normal characters.

Comment: how the heck did that get in there? Maybe from a copy and paste from the docs?

Comment: @AbuMariam Most likely--cutting and pasting from web/visual editors often introduces utter madness for no apparent reason. It was one of those things where it's obvious it *should* work, so I generally check assumptions immediately!

Answer (score 1):

I have tested and received the same error message, but I changed the method to `escapeXml11` and it works now:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils

class Program {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        testStringUtils()
    }

    private static void testStringUtils() {
        def value = "[Apple MacBook Pro with Touch Bar - 15.4 & Core i7 - 16 GB RAM - 512 GB SSD]"
        def sample = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(value)
        println(sample)
    }
}
```

I am using version 3.9:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'
```

This is the output:

```
> Task :Program.main()
[Apple MacBook Pro with Touch Bar - 15.4 &amp; Core i7 - 16 GB RAM - 512 GB SSD]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
17:24:42: Task execution finished 'Program.main()'.
```

Comment: which version of org.apache.commons.commons-text are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.9: `compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'`. Get it [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.9)

Comment: You guys are conflating lang3 and text; those are different packages.